# How can I disable the bodyparser for one API route method, but enable it for another?

Tags: next.js

As the question states, how can I disable the bodyparser for one API route method, but enable it for another?

Here's part of my API route:

```
const handler = async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === "POST") {
            ...
    } else if (req.method === "DELETE") {
            ...
    } else {
        res.status(405).json({
            data: null,
            error: "Method not allowed."
        });
        return;
    };
};

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};

export default handler;
```

You'll see at the bottom of the code block that the body parser applies to both methods at the moment. I need to use the body parser for the DELETE method so that I can access a variable set within the body, but it needs to be disabled for the POST method (handling of multipart forms for image uploads).

I've thought about splitting these into two different files as follows:

**Current setup:**

- /api/advert/[advertId]/image/index.jsx

**Potential setup:**

- /api/advert/[advertId]/image/post.jsx
- /api/advert/[advertId]/image/delete.jsx

While this would work, it would deviate the structure from the rest of my code and so I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to achieve this? (Preferably without the use of additional middleware)

Thanks